# Firefox crashes during launch in Xubuntu 19.04

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, firefox

I installed Xubuntu 19.04 today and it has the same problem that I was facing with Lubuntu too. Firefox crashes when I launch it, especially when I open YouTube or Google. The report shows the following error (Firefox worked just fine on Debian and Linux Mint):

```
Add-ons: formautofill%40mozilla.org:1.0,screenshots%40mozilla.org:35.0.0,webcompat%40mozilla.org:3.0.2
BuildID: 20190410124846
ContentSandboxCapabilities: 119
ContentSandboxCapable: 1
ContentSandboxLevel: 4
CrashTime: 1568874081
DOMIPCEnabled: 1
Email: mihirmishra015@gmail.com
EventLoopNestingLevel: 1
FramePoisonBase: 9223372036600930304
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1568871586
Notes: Ubuntu 19.04FP(D00-L1000-W00000000-T000) WR? WR- OMTP? OMTP+1 OpenGL: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) 915G -- 1.4 Mesa 19.0.2 -- texture_from_pixmap
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SafeMode: 0
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 114
StartupCrash: 0
StartupTime: 1568874052
TelemetryEnvironment: {"build":{"applicationId":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","applicationName":"Firefox","architecture":"x86-64","buildId":"20190410124846","version":"66.0.3","vendor":"Mozilla","displayVersion":"66.0.3","platformVersion":"66.0.3","xpcomAbi":"x86_64-gcc3","updaterAvailable":false},"partner":{"distributionId":"canonical","distributionVersion":"1.0","partnerId":"ubuntu","distributor":"canonical","distributorChannel":"ubuntu","partnerNames":["ubuntu"]},"system":{"memoryMB":1983,"virtualMaxMB":null,"cpu":{"count":2,"cores":2,"vendor":"GenuineIntel","family":6,"model":23,"stepping":10,"l2cacheKB":2048,"l3cacheKB":2048,"speedMHz":null,"extensions":["hasMMX","hasSSE","hasSSE2","hasSSE3","hasSSSE3"]},"os":{"name":"Linux","version":"5.0.0-29-generic","locale":"en-IN"},"hdd":{"profile":{"model":null,"revision":null},"binary":{"model":null,"revision":null},"system":{"model":null,"revision":null}},"gfx":{"D2DEnabled":null,"DWriteEnabled":null,"ContentBackend":"Skia","LowEndMachine":false,"adapters":[{"description":"Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) 915G ","vendorID":"Intel Open Source Technology Center","deviceID":"Mesa DRI Intel(R) 915G ","subsysID":null,"RAM":null,"driver":null,"driverVersion":"1.4 Mesa 19.0.2","driverDate":null,"GPUActive":true}],"monitors":[],"features":{"compositor":"basic","gpuProcess":{"status":"unused"},"wrQualified":{"status":"blocked"},"webrender":{"status":"unavailable"}}},"appleModelId":null},"settings":{"blocklistEnabled":true,"e10sEnabled":true,"e10sMultiProcesses":8,"telemetryEnabled":false,"locale":"en-US","intl":{"requestedLocales":["en-IN"],"availableLocales":["en-US"],"appLocales":["en-US","und"],"systemLocales":["en-IN"],"regionalPrefsLocales":["en-IN"],"acceptLanguages":["en-US","en"]},"update":{"channel":"release","enabled":true,"autoDownload":false},"userPrefs":{"browser.cache.disk.capacity":1048576,"browser.search.region":"IN","browser.search.widget.inNavBar":false},"sandbox":{"effectiveContentProcessLevel":4},"addonCompatibilityCheckEnabled":true,"isDefaultBrowser":false,"defaultSearchEngine":"google","defaultSearchEngineData":{"name":"Google","loadPath":"[distribution]/searchplugins/locale/en-US/google.xml","origin":"default","submissionURL":"https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"}},"profile":{"creationDate":18158,"firstUseDate":18158},"addons":{"activeAddons":{"formautofill@mozilla.org":{"version":"1.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":17996,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":null,"name":"Form Autofill","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":17996},"screenshots@mozilla.org":{"version":"35.0.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":17996,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":"Take clips and screenshots from the Web and save them temporarily or permanently.","name":"Firefox Screenshots","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":17996},"webcompat@mozilla.org":{"version":"3.0.2","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":17996,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":"Urgent post-release fixes for web compatibility.","name":"Web Compat","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":17996}},"theme":{"id":"default-theme@mozilla.org","blocklisted":false,"description":"A theme with the operating system color scheme.","name":"Default","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"","scope":1,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":0,"updateDay":0},"activePlugins":[],"activeGMPlugins":{"gmp-gmpopenh264":{"version":null,"userDisabled":false,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1}},"persona":"default-theme@mozilla.org"},"experiments":{"pref-rollout-block-autoplay-release-66-1535667":{"branch":"active","type":"normandy-prefrollout"}}}
ThreadIdNameMapping: 5877:"Gecko_IOThread",5879:"JS Helper",5881:"Timer",5880:"JS Helper",5878:"JS Watchdog",5882:"Link Monitor",5883:"Socket Thread",5894:"Cache2 I/O",5895:"Cookie",5899:"GMPThread",5900:"Worker Launcher",5901:"SoftwareVsyncThread",5902:"Compositor",5903:"ImgDecoder #1",5904:"ImageIO",5909:"ImageBridgeChild",5910:"IPDL Background",5911:"DOM Worker",5912:"HTML5 Parser",5936:"FS Broker 5934",5937:"ProcessHangMon",5955:"ImgDecoder #2",5965:"DataStorage",5970:"DNS Resolver #1",5971:"URL Classifier",5972:"Classifier Update",5973:"Cache I/O",5981:"mozStorage #1",5985:"mozStorage #2",5987:"mozStorage #3",5997:"FS Broker 5989",6007:"mozStorage #4",6008:"DOM Worker",6009:"localStorage DB",6016:"QuotaManager IO",6019:"FS Broker 6017",6026:"IndexedDB #1",6030:"IndexedDB #3",6034:"mozStorage #5",6042:"SSL Cert #1",6043:"IndexedDB #4",6045:"DOM Worker",6046:"Lazy Idle",6064:"DNS Resolver #2",6067:"SSL Cert #2",6073:"StreamTrans #45",6078:"FS Broker 6076",6079:"DOM Worker",6089:"DNS Resolver #3",6093:"SaveScripts",
Throttleable: 1
URL: https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=youtube&uilel=3&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26app%3Ddesktop%26hl%3Den%26next%3D%252F&hl=en&ec=65620&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin
UptimeTS: 29.16310686
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 66.0.3
useragent_locale: en-US

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

Comment: What is that you pasted?  The crash file?   It doesn't belong on a user support site; but should be filed correctly via launchpad (`ubuntu-bug /var/crash/[filename.crash]`)  -- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: It the the error details and I've reported it already.

Comment: If it was a new report and not a duplicate (ie. it has launchpad bug number) posting that may have provided more clues.  Bug reports have more information, plus they tell you were the information comes from  (ie. if output from you attempting to run from terminal, OR copied from log files, OR taken from a crash report.OR something I've not considered) as I asked what it was hoping to get a clue of where you obtained it...